# Trying to convert from c# string to SQL binary

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, binary, varchar

I am building a c# application that needs to work with the binary(16) unique identifiers in our SQL Server db. Currently, the application is storing these as a string.

I was hoping to be able to pass the unique id as a string into a varchar parameter and convert within the sql statement, but I am getting some strange results.

```
    CONVERT(binary(16), '0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A', 1)
    --desired: 0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A
    --actual: 0x307836454335434145363144463338383430423845464543324435413135
```

Is there some way to convert this in this way? This is the solution I found in various places, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I have also tried some other recommendations:

```
    CONVERT(binary(16), '0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A', [1-3])
    CONVERT(varbinary(16), '0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A', [1-3])
    CONVERT(binary(16), '6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A', [1-3])
    CONVERT(varbinary(16), '6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A', [1-3])
    CAST('' AS XML).value('sql:variable("@Variable")', 'binary(16)')
```

to no avail.

I can store these differently within my application if that is preferable, but I'm unsure what datatype to use? To my knowledge, there is no binary equivalent in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's already binary.  You don't need to convert it and you don't need the quotes around it.  Just use a binary type parameter instead of varchar.

Comment: I think what Jim is saying is that you can do something like this `declare @id binary(16) = 0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A`.  Notice how there are no quotes around the binary data.

Comment: Yes, what Dana said :)

Comment: Can you show the actual code that yields the `0x307...` value? I can't reproduce that problem.

Comment: I am using a Parameter object in c# that won't allow me to put a string into a Parameter with dbtype="binary". My problem overall is getting the c# string into a binary(16) variable in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the uniqueidentifier example to work, but this solution a coworker pointed out seems to work.

```
    DECLARE @id varchar(max)
    DECLARE @idNew binary(16)
    SET @id = '0x6EC5CAE61DF38840B8EFEC2D5A158B3A'
    SET @idNew = cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(substring(sql:variable("@id"), 3) )', 'varbinary(max)')

    select @idNew
```

I fully understand how xQuery works, but this seems to be converting it correctly.

With this, I am able to pass the c# string to the @id variable, convert, and use @idNew within the sql statement.

**EDIT:**

credit/more info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If that is a SQL uniqueidentifier, then the C# equivalent is a GUID.